# Позиционирование div поверх таблицы относительно нее

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка

Мне необходимо разместить div поверх таблицы, что бы его можно было перемещать относительно ячеек этой таблицы.

Вот [пример](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.0.1/demos/agenda-views.html), подскажите как получить схожий эффект, про что (и где) почитать?

Comment: почитайте jquery ui draggable и droppable

Comment: я бы изучил код предоставленного примера, и тогда можно было бы добиться не только схожего эффекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте, например, про [HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp),

вот живой пример...

```js
function allowDrop(ev) { ev.preventDefault() };

function drag(ev) { ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id) };

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
};
```

```html
<style>#placeToDrag {width: 120px;height: 30px;padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;}</style>
<body>
  <div id="placeToDrag" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <br>
  <div id="itemToDrag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Перетащи меня</div>
</body>
```